# File upload fails, when posting with Indy and filename contains Greek characters

Tags: delphi, utf-8, indy10, delphi-xe3, idhttp

I am trying to implement a `POST` to a web service. I need to send a file whose type is variable (`.docx`, `.pdf`, `.txt`) along with a JSON formatted string.

I have manage to post files successfully with code similar to the following:

```
procedure DoRequest;
var
  Http: TIdHTTP;
  Params: TIdMultipartFormDataStream;
  RequestStream, ResponseStream: TStringStream;
  JRequest, JResponse: TJSONObject;
  url: string;
begin
  url := 'some_custom_service'

  JRequest := TJSONObject.Create;
  JResponse := TJSONObject.Create;
  try
    JRequest.AddPair('Pair1', 'Value1');
    JRequest.AddPair('Pair2', 'Value2');
    JRequest.AddPair('Pair3', 'Value3');

    Http := TIdHTTP.Create(nil);           
    ResponseStream := TStringStream.Create;
    RequestStream := TStringStream.Create(UTF8Encode(JRequest.ToString));
    try   
      Params := TIdMultipartFormDataStream.Create;
      Params.AddFile('File', ceFileName.Text, '').ContentTransfer := '';
      Params.AddFormField('Json', 'application/json', '', RequestStream);

      Http.Post(url, Params, ResponseStream);
      JResponse := TJSONObject.ParseJSONValue(ResponseStream.DataString) as TJSONObject;
    finally    
      RequestStream.Free;
      ResponseStream.Free;
      Params.Free;
      Http.Free;
    end;
  finally
    JRequest.Free;
    JResponse.Free;
  end;
end;
```

The problem appears when I try to send a file that contains Greek characters and spaces in the filename. Sometimes it fails and sometimes it succeeds.

After a lot of research, I notice that the `POST` header is encoded by Indy's `TIdFormDataField` class using the `EncodeHeader()` function.  When the post fails, the encoded filename in the header is split, compared to the successful post where is not split.

For example :

- `Επιστολή εκπαιδευτικο.docx` is encoded as `=?UTF-8?B?zpXPgM65z4PPhM6/zrvOriDOtc66z4DOsc65zrTOtc+Fz4TOuc66zr8uZG9j?='#$D#$A' =?UTF-8?B?eA==?=`, which fails.
- `Επιστολή εκπαιδευτικ.docx` is encoded as 
  `=?UTF-8?B?zpXPgM65z4PPhM6/zrvOriDOtc66z4DOsc65zrTOtc+Fz4TOuc66LmRvY3g=?=`,  which succeeds.
- `Επιστολή εκπαιδευτικ .docx` is encoded as 
  `=?UTF-8?B?zpXPgM65z4PPhM6/zrvOriDOtc66z4DOsc65zrTOtc+Fz4TOuc66?= .docx`, which fails.

I have tried to change the encoding of the filename, the `AContentType` of the `AddFile()` procedure, and the `ContentTransfer`, but none of those change the behavior, and I still get errors when the encoded filename is split.

Is this some kind of bug, or am I missing something?

My code works for every case except those I described above.

I am using Delphi XE3 with Indy10.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`EncodeHeader()` does have some known issues with Unicode strings:

[EncodeHeader() needs to take codeunits into account when splitting data between adjacent encoded-words](http://indy.codeplex.com/workitem/24678)

Basically, an MIME-encoded word cannot be more than 75 characters in length, so long text gets split up.  But when encoding a long Unicode string, any given Unicode character may be charset-encoded using 1 or more bytes, and `EncodeHeader()` does not yet avoid erroneously splitting a multi-byte character between two individual bytes into separate encoded words (which is illegal and explicitly forbidden by [RFC 2047](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2047) of the MIME spec).

However, that is not what is happening in your examples.

In your first example, `'Επιστολή εκπαιδευτικο.docx'` is too long to be encoded as a single MIME word, so it gets split into `'Επιστολή εκπαιδευτικο.doc'` `'x'` substrings, which are then encoded separately.  **This is legal in MIME for long text** (though you might have expected Indy to split the text into `'Επιστολή'` `' εκπαιδευτικο.doc'` instead, or even `'Επιστολή'` `' εκπαιδευτικο'` `'.doc'`. That might be a possibility in a future release).  Adjacent MIME words that are separated by only whitespace are meant to be concatenated together without separating whitespace when decoded, thus producing `'Επιστολή εκπαιδευτικο.docx'` again.  If the server is not doing that, it has a flaw in its decoder (maybe it is decoding as `'Επιστολή εκπαιδευτικο.doc x'` instead?).

In your second example, `'Επιστολή εκπαιδευτικ.docx'` is short enough to be encoded as a single MIME word.

In your third example, `'Επιστολή εκπαιδευτικ .docx'` gets split on the second whitespace (not the first) into `'Επιστολή εκπαιδευτικ'` `' .docx'` substrings, and only the first substring needs to be encoded.  **This is legal in MIME**.  When decoded, the decoded text is meant to be concatenated with the following unencoded text, preserving whitespace between them, thus producing `'Επιστολή εκπαιδευτικ .docx'` again.  If the server is not doing that, it has a flaw in its decoder (maybe it is decoding as `'Επιστολή εκπαιδευτικ.docx'` instead?).

If you run these example filenames through Indy's MIME header encoder/decoder, they do decode properly:

```
var
  s: String;
begin
  s := EncodeHeader('Επιστολή εκπαιδευτικο.docx', '', 'B', 'UTF-8');
  ShowMessage(s); // '=?UTF-8?B?zpXPgM65z4PPhM6/zrvOriDOtc66z4DOsc65zrTOtc+Fz4TOuc66zr8uZG9j?='#13#10' =?UTF-8?B?eA==?='
  s := DecodeHeader(s);
  ShowMessage(s); // 'Επιστολή εκπαιδευτικο.docx'

  s := EncodeHeader('Επιστολή εκπαιδευτικ.docx', '', 'B', 'UTF-8');
  ShowMessage(s); // '=?UTF-8?B?zpXPgM65z4PPhM6/zrvOriDOtc66z4DOsc65zrTOtc+Fz4TOuc66LmRvY3g=?='
  s := DecodeHeader(s);
  ShowMessage(s); // 'Επιστολή εκπαιδευτικ.docx' 

  s := EncodeHeader('Επιστολή εκπαιδευτικ .docx', '', 'B', 'UTF-8');
  ShowMessage(s); // '=?UTF-8?B?zpXPgM65z4PPhM6/zrvOriDOtc66z4DOsc65zrTOtc+Fz4TOuc66?= .docx' 
  s := DecodeHeader(s);
  ShowMessage(s); // 'Επιστολή εκπαιδευτικ .docx'
end;
```

So the problem seems to be on the server side decoding, not on Indy's client side encoding.

That being said, if you are using a fairly recent version of Indy 10 (Nov 2011 or later), `TIdFormDataField` has a `HeaderEncoding` property, which defaults to `'B'` (base64) in Unicode environments.  However, the splitting logic also affects `'Q'` (quoted-printable) as well, so that may or may not work for you, either (but you can try it):

```
with Params.AddFile('File', ceFileName.Text, '') do
begin
  ContentTransfer := '';
  HeaderEncoding := 'Q'; // <--- here
  HeaderCharSet := 'utf-8';
end;
```

Otherwise, a workaround might be to change the value to `'8'` (8-bit) instead, which effectively disables MIME encoding (but not charset encoding):

```
with Params.AddFile('File', ceFileName.Text, '') do
begin
  ContentTransfer := '';
  HeaderEncoding := '8'; // <--- here
  HeaderCharSet := 'utf-8';
end;
```

Just note that if the server is not expecting raw UTF-8 bytes for the filename, you might still run into problems (ie, `'Επιστολή εκπαιδευτικο.docx'` being interpreted as `'Î•Ï€Î¹ÏƒÏ„Î¿Î»Î® ÎµÎºÏ€Î±Î¹Î´ÎµÏ…Ï„Î¹ÎºÎ¿.docx'`, for instance).

Comment: Thank you very much @Remy for the answer and all the explanation. I have contacted with the server owner and we will try to debug it together. In the meanwhile i tried the second workaround (8-bit) and worked like a charm.